# How to manage a Apache Spark context in Django?

Tags: python, django, apache-spark

I have a Django application that interacts with a Cassandra database and I want to try using Apache Spark to run operations on this database. I have some experience with Django and Cassandra but I'm new to Apache Spark.

I know that to interact with a Spark cluster first I need to create a SparkContext, something like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

My question is the following: how should I treat this context? Should I instantiate it when my application starts and let it live during it's execution or should I start a SparkContext everytime before running an operation in the cluster and then kill it when the operation finishes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For the last days I've been working on this, since no one answered I will post what was my approach.

Apparently creating a SparkContext generates a bit of overhead, so stopping the context after every operation is not a good idea.

Also, there is no downfall, apparently, on letting the context live while the application runs.

Therefore, my approach was treating the SparkContext like a database connection, I created a singleton that instantiates the context when the application starts running and used it where needed.

I hope this can be helpful to someone, and I am open to new suggestions on how to deal with this, I'm still new to Apache Spark.

Comment: Could you give more details on how you did that please

Comment: Hi Beatriz. I have worked more extensively with Apache Spark since I posted this question here. This implementation that I did was probably not the best use of it. But what I did was create a class that instantiates the Spark Context and then when I need to run something on Spark I used this context accessing as a class attribute. This way the context starts when the application starts and I can use it when the application lives. You can find the code here https://github.com/pedromb/wikiolapbase/blob/master/wob_data_upload/handles/spark_handle.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Were you ever able to integrate Spark completely with the Django application. I'm curious

Comment: Well, this was the first time I was using Apache Spark, so I did not have much experience with it. But I guess yes, I was able to integrate with the Django application, I'm just not sure if it was the best way of doing it. Basically I start a Spark Cluster, and then I start a Spark Context from within the Django Application, the way I coded was not the way I intended to do, but I think the best way of doing is creating a singleton to be sure the context is started only once, and then you can use this context to send jobs to Spark when needed.

Comment: Hey @PedroBernardo Can you tell me how you initiated the SparkContext and kept it alive? Did you use it as a global variable in views.py and then pass it ask an argument to the tasks?